# Outlined text field in WP Form for contact form

Tags: wordpress, forms, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Routine label for forms are always on top of them, but I would like to know how to put label like outline text specially when you have WP Form plugin in Wordpress.
This is what I mean:

[image]

I know how to do it with html and css but it is not easy with WP Form:

[image]

I couldn't find it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I actually created this in a recent project, which were I used Contact Form 7 (I prefer that plugin instead of WP Form). But nevertheless, u can achieve something like this with simple CSS, HTML and a little bit of JavaScript. Run the code-snippet for yourself and see what I did.

What we actually did is:

- Hide the placeholder with: opacity 0, to prevent accessibility loss (people who are blind, can actually hear the placeholder if they focus on the input.
- Create an floating label, that comes after the input, so it is on-top of the input.
- Style the floating label based on the current input states. If it's active, then it goes to the top.
- Then, when focussing the input, the JavaScript function will trigger and it will look if the input is still empty- or not. If it's not empty: add the class 'is-not-empty'.
- With that class we can say to the label: Stay on top, my man!

```js
const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.input-wrapper');
wrappers.forEach( (wrapper) => {
  input = wrapper.children[0];

  input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
    if (e.target.value !== '') {
      wrapper.classList.remove('is-empty');
      wrapper.classList.add('is-not-empty');
    } else {
      wrapper.classList.add('is-empty');
      wrapper.classList.remove('is-not-empty');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control {
     margin-bottom: 18px !important;
     height: 64px;
     margin-top: 0 !important;
     color: var(--bs-dark) !important;
}
 .form-control.wpcf7-textarea {
     height: auto;
}
 .form-control::placeholder {
    /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
     opacity: 0;
}
 .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
     opacity: 0;
}
 .form-control::-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* Microsoft Edge */
     opacity: 0;
}
 .form-wrapper .input-wrapper {
     position: relative;
}
 .form-wrapper input:focus ~ .floating-label, .form-wrapper textarea:focus ~ .floating-label, .form-wrapper .is-not-empty .floating-label {
     top: -13px;
     bottom: 10px;
     left: 20px;
     font-size: 14px;
     opacity: 1;
     background: #fff;
     height: 30px;
     color: #333;
     padding: 6px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}
 .form-wrapper .floating-label {
     position: absolute;
     pointer-events: none;
     left: 20px;
     top: 23px;
     transition: 0.2s ease all;
     white-space: nowrap;
     max-width: 61vw;
     overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="email" name="emailadres" size="40" minlength="5" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-email form-control" id="emailadres" aria-invalid="false" value=''>

    <label for="emailadres" class="floating-label">Your mail address here</label>

  </div>
</div>
```